# ffmpeg uninstall from centos 6.6

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to remove ffmpeg and install the newest version but I can't get the old version out. This is the error when trying to install:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libpostproc.pc from install of ffmpeg-devel-2    .2.1-65.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ffmpeg-libpostproc-    0.6.5-1.el6.rf.x86_64
  file /usr/include/libpostproc/postprocess.h from install of ffmpeg-    devel-2.2.1-65.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ffmpeg-    libpostproc-0.6.5-1.el6.rf.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libpostproc.a from install of ffmpeg-devel-2.2.1-65.el6    .x86_64 conflicts with file from package ffmpeg-libpostproc-0.6.5-1.el6    .rf.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libpostproc.so from install of ffmpeg-devel-2.2.1-65.    el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ffmpeg-libpostproc-0.6.5-1.    el6.rf.x86_64
```

Can someone help me with this issue? I have tried `make ubinstall` but that does not work, nor does `yum remove ffmpe`g nor the command `yum erase ffmpeg x264 x264-devel`.

Answer (score 1):

Try: yum remove ffmpeg-libpostproc

Answer (score 0):

If you had originally installed the package from source (by `#make install`):

`#make uninstall`

If there is no uninstall, view the install procedure:

`#make -n install`

and reverse the install procedure:

1. Uninstall all packages you installed (e.g. by `#yum remove ffmpeg`, or `#cd ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/x264` and `#make uninstall`)
2. Remove all directories/files created

---

For example, this is what I ended up doing:

```
#yum remove ffmpeg
#cd ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg
#make uninstall
#make -n install
#cd ../x264
#make uninstall
rm -f /home/username/ffmpeg_build/include/x264.h /home/username/ffmpeg_build/include/x264_config.h /home/username/ffmpeg_build/lib/libx264.a
rm -f /home/username/bin/x264 /home/username/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig/x264.pc
rm -f /home/username/ffmpeg_build/lib/libx264.so.161 /home/username/ffmpeg_build/lib/libx264.so
rm -f /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/x264
#cd ../yasm
#make uninstall
#make -n install
#cd ../nasm
#make uninstall
#make -n install
#cd ../..
#rm -rf ffmpeg_sources
#rm -rf ~/ffmpeg_build
#rm -rf ~/bin
```